# iOS: Button events in Custom UIViewController Containment do not work

Tags: ios, button, uiviewcontroller, containment

I am implementing a custom UIViewController Containment.

Also I am adding buttons to child view controllers' views 
down in hierarchy.

The problem is that button events never fire when buttons
are in child view controllers down in hierarchy. They work
only if placed up to one level below root level - parentTopVc.

Architecture is like this:

the root is at: self.window.rootViewController = rootVc

hierarchy:

0-----rootVc

1-----------parentTopVc <--- button events DO fire

2----------------------firstTopVc  <--- button events do NOT fire

2----------------------secondTopVc <--- button events do NOT fire

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIViewController *rootVc;
UIViewController *parentTopVc;
UIViewController *firstTopVc;
UIViewController *secondTopVc;

rootVc = [UIViewController new];
self.window.rootViewController = rootVc;

parentTopVc = [UIViewController new];
[rootVc addChildViewController:parentTopVc]; 


[parentTopVc didMoveToParentViewController:rootVc];
//
parentTopVc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[rootVc.view addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:parentTopVc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
relatedBy:0
toItem:rootVc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[rootVc.view  addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:parentTopVc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
relatedBy:0
toItem:rootVc.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
multiplier:1 constant:50]];

[rootVc.view  addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:parentTopVc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
relatedBy:0
toItem:rootVc.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[rootVc.view  addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:parentTopVc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
relatedBy:0
toItem:rootVc.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[parentTopVc.view addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:parentTopVc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
relatedBy:0
toItem:nil attribute:0
multiplier:1 constant:200]];

[rootVc.view addSubview: parentTopVc.view];
parentTopVc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


firstTopVc = [UIViewController new];
secondTopVc = [UIViewController new];

[parentTopVc addChildViewController:childVc];
UIView* childVcInnerFrame = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xc,
                                                                   yc,
                                                                   wc,
                                                                   hc)]; //x, y, w, h
[childVc.view addSubview: childVcInnerFrame];



firstTopVc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[parentTopVc.view  addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:firstTopVc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
relatedBy:0
toItem:parentTopVc.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[parentTopVc.view  addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:firstTopVc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
relatedBy:0
toItem:parentTopVc.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
multiplier:1 constant:0]];

// activate
[parentTopVc.view addSubview: firstTopVc.view];
[firstTopVc didMoveToParentViewController:parentTopVc];         


UIView *parentTopVcBtnViewsLevel1frame = [UIView new];

// add view to root
[parentTopVcInnerframeLevel1 addSubview: parentTopVcBtnViewsLevel1frame];

UIView *vtemp1;
vtemp1 = [UIView new];

[parentTopVcBtnViewsLevel1frame addSubview: vtemp1];

vtemp1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[parentTopVcBtnViewsLevel1frame addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:vtemp1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
relatedBy:0
toItem:parentTopVcBtnViewsLevel1frame attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
multiplier:1 constant:10]];

[parentTopVcBtnViewsLevel1frame addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:vtemp1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
relatedBy:0
toItem:parentTopVcBtnViewsLevel1frame attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
multiplier:1 constant:10]];

//v1: W
[vtemp1 addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:vtemp1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
relatedBy:0
toItem:nil attribute:0
multiplier:1 constant:w]];

//v1: H
[vtemp1 addConstraint:
[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:vtemp1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
relatedBy:0
toItem:nil attribute:0
multiplier:1 constant:h]];

// button
btnInView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; //
[btnInView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
btnInView.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

[btnInView setFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,w,h)]; // set up frame
[vtemp1 addSubview:btnInView]; // place button in view


[btnInView addTarget:self action:@selector(doShowNextTopVc:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

//
-(void) doShowNextTopVc:(UIButton *)paramSender{
NSLog(@"doShowNextTopVc: %@", @"START <==");
}
```

doShowNextTopVc never fires

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that your touch events aren't going through to your sub-root level view controllers because you're not correctly using them in a custom container. It is also possible that your ViewController pointers are not retained after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` completes. There is no way to know without providing more code.

**[EDIT]** I'm clarifying my answer based on what I've found via the comments.

1. I/we can't help the original poster without more code and a deeper understanding of how the app is being written, compiled and run. The comments below outline some of the questions asked, already.
2. It is not clear how the AppDelegate code is being generated as the original poster mentioned that he/she can't post it in its entirety and that it is somehow being generated automatically.
3. There are variables in the code provided whose pointer declarations are not provided. They are: `childVC`, `parentTopVCInnerframeLevel1`, and `btnInView`. `btnInView` may not be retained after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` completes, which might be part of the problem.
4. The provided source code seems to unnecessarily call `didMoveToParentViewController:`. There is no UIViewController subclassing here so it doesn't need to be called. Try removing it. Again, it is not clear how the AppDelegate code is being created or written, or if the original poster can actually do that.

Finally ....

If you want a custom view controller container class I would consider reading through Apple's View Controller Programming Guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

I would definitely read the section on the left titled **Creating Custom Container View Controllers** and it's sub section titled **Implementing a Custom Container View Controller**

Comment: Thank you. I read the information in the above links and other.

There is not any run time warnings, the code is working save the events not firing. They fire only on the first level below the root.
I am not using NIB because I am generating the code programmatically.

Comment: Where is childVC declared? In your AppDelegate's header file? If so, can you provide that code as well?

Comment: I am having problems posting

Comment: I need to see all the code in AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m to have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: sorry - it is copied from the project:

[parentTopVc addChildViewController:firstTopVc];

UIView* childVcInnerFrame = [[UIView alloc] 

initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xc,yc,wc,hc)]; //x, y, w, h

[firstTopVc.view addSubview: childVcInnerFrame];

Comment: On about line 61 of the code in your original post you add a variable called `childVc` as a child to `parentTopVc`. One of my questions is where is `childVc` declared? Also, it would be really helpful if you edited your original post and included the code for AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m in their entirety.

Comment: All code is in AppDelegate.m because it is generated from JSON file. Probably it should be in viewLoad in a separate class?

Comment: childVc is actually firstTopVc

Comment: JSON file? How are you building / running you app? Natively with Xcode or some other tool?

Comment: I read a JSON file, interpret it and build the interface automatically. It is all in AppDelegate.m and practically all the code.It allows much more flexibility. No NIBs, storyboards, etc. All is defined in JSON and easy to change. Can be updated remotely for small changes. All works fine except these button events. Fully custom interface with transitions between several levels. Impossible to do and maintain in traditional way - too much information.

Comment: Then, please post AppDelegate.m in its entirety in your original post.

Comment: Why not? If its too long, break it up into chunks. Finally, and where are the pointers to `childVc`, `parentTopVCInnerframeLevel1` and `btnInView` declared? Can you post that code? If you're interpreting JSON and building your AppDelegate dynamically you'll need to provide more information in your original post that explains how you're building, compiling and running your application. It helps to be as thorough as possible in explaining your problem.